# How could I authenticate a user in facebook using oauth?

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-graph-api

I want to know how could I authenticate a user, visiting my site, for facebook using oAuth 2.0

Comment: If you think that you're going to get better answers here than reading the docs (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), you're wrong... Is there something *specific* that you don't understand?

Comment: Adding to what @DemianBrecht said, what language are you using?!

Comment: @ifaour I am using javascript, jquery, and PHP with a hint of AJAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the javascript sdk.

Basically go here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Add the code to async load the fb all.js

Then authenticating can take many paths... you can do this:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

or pass them to here:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL

The you can make proper graph calls to get any necessary info you need with the graph like so:

FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert(response.name);
});

Further information on that is available here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

Hope this helps.